# Excluir cadastro da tabela javascript React

Tags: table, button

Bom dia,
 Não estou conseguindo apagar dados de uma API,
Minha intenção seria colocar um Button numa coluna e quando clicado nesse Button os dados da respectiva linha seria apagado.

Essa é minha primeira postagem no fórum, me avisem caso estiver errado.

```
insira o código aqui
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
import { InputText } from 'primereact/components/inputtext/InputText';
import axios from 'axios';
import './bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css';
import logo from './logo.png';
import Server from './Server';


class App extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        Produtos: [],
        Produto: '',
        Mensagem: ''

    }

}

componentWillMount() {
    axios.get(Server + `/produto/listar`)
        .then(
            (result) => {
                this.setState(result.data);
                if (this.state.Produtos.length > 0) {
                    this.setState({ Produto: this.state.Produtos[0] });
                }
            })
}

novo = () => {
    this.setState({ Produto: { "id": 0, "descricao": "Novo" } });
}

gravar = () => {
    if (this.state.Produto.descricao.length > 100) {
        this.setState({ Mensagem: 'Máximo de 100 posições.' });
        return;
    }
    if (this.state.Produto.id === 0) {
        this.inserir();
    } else {
        this.atualizar();
    }
    this.setState({ Mensagem: 's.' });
}

inserir = () => {
    const d = this.state.Produto.descricao;
    axios.get(Server + `/produto/inserir?descricao=${d}`)
        .then(
            (result) => {
                this.setState({ Produto: result.data });
                this.setState({ Produtos: [...this.state.Produtos, this.state.Produto] });
            })
}

atualizar = () => {
    const i = this.state.Produto.id;
    const d = this.state.Produto.descricao;
    axios.get(Server + `/produto/atualizar?id=${i}&descricao=${d}`)
        .then(
            (result) => {
                var i = this.state.Produtos.findIndex(x => x.id === this.state.Produto.id);
                this.setState({ Produto: result.data });
                var Produtos = [...this.state.Produtos];
                Produtos[i] = this.state.Produto;
                this.setState({ Produtos });
            });
}

apagar = () => {
    if (this.state.Produto.id > 0) {
        const i = 186;
        axios.get(Server +`/produto/apagar?id=${i}`)
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    var i = this.state.Produtos.findIndex(x => x.id === this.state.Produto.id);
                    var Produtos = [...this.state.Produtos];
                    Produtos.splice(i, 1);
                    this.setState({ Produtos });
                    if (this.state.Produtos.length > 0) {
                        this.setState({ Produto: Produtos[0] });
                    }
                });
    }
}

render() {
    const { Produtos, Produto, Mensagem } = this.state

    return (

        <div className={"App"}>
            <span>{Mensagem}</span>

            <div className={"container"}>
                <div className={"row"}>
                    <div className={"col-md-1 logo"}>
                        <img className={"img-logo"} src={logo} alt="logo" />
                    </div>
                    <div className={"col-4"}>
                        <label>ID:{Produto.id}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className={"col-4"}>
                        <InputText value={Produto.descricao} onChange={(e) => this.setState({ Produto: { id: Produto.id, descricao: e.target.value } })} />
                        <button type="button" onClick={this.gravar} className="btn btn-primary">Gravar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className={"row justify-content-center"}>
                    <div clasName="row">
                        <div className={"col-3"}>
                            <button type="button" onClick={this.novo} className="btn btn-primary">Novo</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={"row"}>
                        <div className={"col-3"}>
                            <button type="button" onClick={this.apagar} className="btn btn-danger">Apagar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={"row"}>
                        <div className={"col-3"}>
                            <button type="button" onClick={this.apagar} className="btn btn-info">Alterar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <table id="my_table" className="table table-hover table-responsive-md">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Descricao</th>
                        <th>Index</th>
                        <th>Ações</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        Produtos.map((Produto, index) => { 

                            return (
                                <tr key={index}>
                                    <td>{Produto.id}</td>
                                    <td>{Produto.descricao}</td>
                                    <td>{index}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.apagar}>Deletar</button>
                                        <button className="btn btn-render btn-warning " >Alterar</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>

    )
}
}

export default App;
```